# C# not calculating a decimal result properly

Tags: c#, decimal

(5 / 15) * 1185 should give 395.

```
decimal Test = (5 / 15) * 1185;
```

This, however, returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`5 / 15` is an integer division and returns 0. Use `5m / 15m` to force `decimal`.

`m` is the C# suffix to signify to the compiler that the number your wrote is a `decimal`, even if it looks like an `int`. You can use `f` for floats and `d` for doubles (or `5.0`).

While on the topic of suffixes, there is also `L` for `long` but that wouldn't have helped your with your division because it is also an integer type.

```
5 // Int32
5L // Int64
5d // Double
5.0 // Double
5m // Decimal
5f // Single
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use floating point division, not integer division. You can get the correct result by making it a floating point number, or using `m` (to specify it as a `decimal`) behind the 15:

```
decimal Test = (5 / 15.0) * 1185;
```

or

```
decimal Test = (5 / 15m) * 1185;
```

Answer (score 0):

5/15 is 0 because you are using integer division.
You can try use one of the following code:

```
decimal test = (5m / 15) * 1185
decimal test = ((decimal)5 / 15) * 1185
decimal test = (5.0 / 15) * 1185
```

The Decimal value type represents decimal numbers ranging from positive 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 to negative 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335. The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding but rather minimizes errors due to rounding.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a lambda expression :

```
Func<decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal> exp = (x, y, z) => (x / y) * z;
Console.WriteLine(exp(5, 15, 1185));
```

outputs:
 394.999999

as you are expecting 395 you will need to use a [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(exp(5, 15, 1185), 1));
```

outputs: 395.0